# Is Rails environment the prerequisite for cruisecontrol.rb

Tags: ruby, cruisecontrol

I have no rails environment but I want to use cruisecontrol.rb as my Continous Integration environment.

After following the instrcution from http://cruisecontrolrb.thoughtworks.com/documentation/getting_started and then

```
./cruise start
```

I got the error here: (sorry, but the formatter is better than posting it here directly)
   http://pastebin.ca/1487868

It seems the CC.rb is doing some data migration/backup work when start up, and I could resolve this by comment out corresponding code :

```
#cruisecontrolrb / db / migrate / 002_move_custom_files_to_directory_in_user_home.rb         
DATA_ROOT = ARGV[0]
RAILS_ROOT = File.expand_path(".")     
if File.directory? 'projects'          
  #mv 'projects', DATA_ROOT + '/projects'  #comment out this line, it will work perfect fine
else
  mkdir_p DATA_ROOT + '/projects'
end
```

I debugged a litter bit and found when above code executing, the DATA_ROOT and Dir.pwd are  ~/.cruise. So

```
mv 'projects', DATA_ROOT + '/projects' would become 
mv ~/.cruise/projects ~/.cruise/projects which is obvious not correct
```

What would you recommend to solve this? To redfine DATA_ROOT to what even place I want?

Comment: What directory are you running cc.rb from?

Comment: I was running from ~/.cruise/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways around this, the easiest is probably to create a cruise_config.rb file in the root of your project.  It should look something like this :

```
Project.configure do |project|
  project.rake_task = "spec"
end
```

just replace "spec" with whatever rake task you have.  if you're not using rake (say you're using ant) you can instead do something like this :

```
Project.configure do |project|
  project.build_command = "ant test"
end
```

just replace "ant test" with command line command that will return 0 if successful and 1 otherwise.  (ant, make, rake, all do this)

Comment: Jeremy, I was OK with gettting build result. The problem is migrating fail when start up.